# Time of Last Power Cycle

Tags: centos, power-management, uptime

I know how to use

```
uptime
```

To see how long the OS has been running, and

```
last reboot
```

To see a log of recent OS reboots.

Is there an easy way to see when the box was last power cycled?

The output of the last command includes the line

```
wtmp begins Tue Jan 19 hh:mm:ss yyyy
```

But that is a log which rotates.

Centos 3.10 if the answer is not universal.

On a clone of the box I'm actually interested in I can indirectly get the answer via the BMC management console:

Under the Server Health tab there is a Power Statistics section which tells me "System Power Statistics value over the last n.nn Hours" which reset after I used the management console to power cycle the box.

So the answer is out there.

I don't have ipmitools or showsel installed on this box, and certainly could not get permission to install software on the remote box that is my actual target of interest.

There was a comment (apparently deleted) telling me to check my BIOS version to see if there is something in the docs; the command I found to do that is

> (Root prompt) dmidecode -s bios-version

And more generally

> (root prompt) dmidecode | head -(medium sized number)

So I have a starting point for further research.